# Why is Vite watching files above my project directory?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vite

I'm using Vite 4.1.4.

Sometimes, and I don't know really why, because it seems to be intermitent, when I run "yarn dev", that is

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
```

it freezes and shows an error like this:

```
node:internal/errors:478
    ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);
    ^

Error: ENOSPC: System limit for number of file watchers reached, watch '/home/carlos/dev/github/second-project/var/cache/prod/pools/7mudk7BtgY/W/5/iWI-l9tgYgHZwBl1qkWA'
    at FSWatcher.<computed> (node:internal/fs/watchers:244:19)
    at Object.watch (node:fs:2296:34)
    at createFsWatchInstance (file:///home/carlos/dev/github/crosierfrt-fixhub/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-33545781.js:50429:17)
    at setFsWatchListener (file:///home/carlos/dev/github/crosierfrt-fixhub/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-33545781.js:50476:15)
    at NodeFsHandler._watchWithNodeFs (file:///home/carlos/dev/github/crosierfrt-fixhub/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-33545781.js:50631:14)
    at NodeFsHandler._handleFile (file:///home/carlos/dev/github/crosierfrt-fixhub/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-33545781.js:50695:23)
    at NodeFsHandler._addToNodeFs (file:///home/carlos/dev/github/crosierfrt-fixhub/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-33545781.js:50937:21)
Emitted 'error' event on FSWatcher instance at:
    at FSWatcher._handleError (file:///home/carlos/dev/github/crosierfrt-fixhub/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-33545781.js:52130:10)
    at NodeFsHandler._addToNodeFs (file:///home/carlos/dev/github/crosierfrt-fixhub/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-33545781.js:50945:18) {
  errno: -28,
  syscall: 'watch',
  code: 'ENOSPC',
  path: '/home/carlos/dev/github/bkp/var/cache/prod/pools/7mudk7BtgY/W/5/iWI-l9tgYgHZwBl1qkWA',
  filename: '/home/carlos/dev/github/bkp/var/cache/prod/pools/7mudk7BtgY/W/5/iWI-l9tgYgHZwBl1qkWA'
}
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

But why is vite watching the "/home/carlos/dev/github/second-project/..."...

My project is in /home/carlos/dev/github/my-first-app/ .

Why is it going above the project folder and starts to watching all the other folders?

Sometimes it shows the same folders, but sometimes not.

Really can't understand this.

Comment: Maybe there are some links in your first project that reference the second project. Vite will watch all file that it considers as dependences